# How can I use OrientDB from a Scala / Play 2.2 project?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2, orientdb

I'd like to try [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com/orientdb/) in a Scala / Play 2.2 project, which uses SBT to build. How do I integrate OrientDB into this project? Bear in mind that I'm new to all of these technologies (my background is mainly Python/C#/JavaScript), so I could do with some handholding :)

Preferably, OrientDB should be installed as a managed dependency if that is possible. I'd also like a good Scala API for the database if that is available.

Some example code to connect to OrientDB server from my application would be cool.

**EDIT:**

I've tried the [Play with OrientDB](https://github.com/ratcashdev/play-with-orientdb) Play plugin, but without success so far. What I did was (as per the plugin's [README](https://github.com/ratcashdev/play-with-orientdb)):

1. `cd ~/local/play-2.2.1/`
2. `git clone git@github.com:ratcashdev/play-with-orientdb.git`
3. `cd play-with-orientdb/src`
4. Add `val orientDBVersion = "1.6.4"` to src/build.sbt
5. Edit project/build.properties as: `sbt.version=0.13.0`
6. Change the last line of project/plugins.sbt to: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")`
7. Remove project/Build.scala (as this caused build errors)
8. `play publish-local`
9. Add `"ratcash.net" % "play-with-orientdb_2.10" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"` to the `libraryDependencies` setting of my project's build.sbt file
10. Add `val orientDBVersion = "1.6.4"` to my project's build.sbt file
11. Edit my project's conf/play.plugins file as: `10000:modules.orientdb.ODBPlugin`
12. Add OrientDB configuration to my project's conf/application.conf file.
13. Run my project via `play run`
14. Visit localhost:9000

The last step results in an error page displaying the following exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: modules.orientdb.ODBPlugin`.

Comment: did you manage to get it working? I too was thinking of using orientdb with play!

Comment: @DenisRosca Hi, I did somehow hack it into working. I'm going to try to write down here what I had to do.

Comment: @DenisRosca I've posted an answer with the changes I made. I think they're correct, although I'm totally new to Play/Scala etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I had to hack the [Play with OrientDB plugin](https://github.com/ratcashdev/play-with-orientdb) to make it work with Play 2.2 / SBT 0.13, and eventually made it work as far as I can tell. I forked the original project and shared my changes on [GitHub](https://github.com/aknuds1/play-with-orientdb/). I've pasted below my patch against the original source code that was necessary to use it from Play 2.2:

```
 diff --git a/src/app/modules/orientdb/actions/ODBTransactionWrapper.java b/src/app/modules/orientdb/actions/ODBTransactionWrapper.java
 index 348276b..753317c 100644
 --- a/src/app/modules/orientdb/actions/ODBTransactionWrapper.java
 +++ b/src/app/modules/orientdb/actions/ODBTransactionWrapper.java
 @@ -6,14 +6,15 @@ import modules.orientdb.ODB.DBTYPE;
  import modules.orientdb.annotation.Transactional;
  import play.mvc.Action;
  import play.mvc.Http;
 -import play.mvc.Result;
 +import play.mvc.SimpleResult;
 +import play.libs.F.Promise;

  public class ODBTransactionWrapper extends Action<Transactional>
  {
      @Override
 -    public Result call(Http.Context context) throws Throwable
 +    public Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context context) throws Throwable
      {
 -      Result res = ok("Did nothing");
 +      Promise<SimpleResult> res;
        //internalServerError();
        try {
            beforeInvocation();
 @@ -23,6 +24,7 @@ public class ODBTransactionWrapper extends Action<Transactional>
            System.out.println("exception happened.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            onInvocationException(e);
 +            throw e;
        } finally {
            System.out.println("cleanup");
            invocationFinally();
 @@ -34,7 +36,6 @@ public class ODBTransactionWrapper extends Action<Transactional>
        DBTYPE type = this.getClass().getAnnotation(Transactional.class).db();
        if(type == DBTYPE.DOCUMENT || type == DBTYPE.OBJECT)
            Model.objectDB().begin();
 -
      }

      public void invocationFinally() {
 diff --git a/src/project/Build.scala b/src/project/Build.scala
 index f9301ee..c85e2c1 100644
 --- a/src/project/Build.scala
 +++ b/src/project/Build.scala
 @@ -1,17 +1,16 @@
  import sbt._
  import Keys._
 -import PlayProject._

  object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

 -    val appName         = "Play with OrientDB"
 +    val appName         = "play-with-orientdb"
      val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

      // IMPORTANT. The plugin can't be compiled without this
 -    val orientDBVersion = "1.3.0-SNAPSHOT"
 +    val orientDBVersion = "1.6.4"

      val appDependencies = Seq(
 -      javaCore
 +      //javaCore

        // disable JDBC and javaEBean
        //javaJdbc,
 diff --git a/src/project/build.properties b/src/project/build.properties
 index 82f1ca3..8cbb522 100644
 --- a/src/project/build.properties
 +++ b/src/project/build.properties
 @@ -1 +1 @@
 -sbt.version=0.12.2-RC2
 \ No newline at end of file
 +sbt.version=0.13.0
 \ No newline at end of file
 diff --git a/src/project/plugins.sbt b/src/project/plugins.sbt
 index 92ccea5..a815558 100644
 --- a/src/project/plugins.sbt
 +++ b/src/project/plugins.sbt
 @@ -5,4 +5,4 @@ logLevel := Level.Warn
  resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

  // Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
 -addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1-RC2")
 \ No newline at end of file
 +addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
 \ No newline at end of file
```

I haven't got as far as to make real use of this plugin, except include it in my application. I can see that the plugin is able to connect to OrientDB upon server startup though, so it should be usable from here on.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of this page, there's a list of Play Framework plugins for OrientDB:
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Plugins

One of the plugins listed, Origami plugin (which Sari HH mentioned in another answer), supports Scala models, and has apparently been updated to Play 2.2 although the repo link indicates it's for 2.1 only: https://github.com/sgougi/play21-origami-plugin

(I haven't tested these plugens myself.)

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of this index of Play plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [plugin](https://github.com/ratcashdev/play-with-orientdb) that enables you to use OrientDB from PlayFramework 2.x, and here is a [mapper](https://github.com/sgougi/play21-origami-plugin) from PlayFramework models to OrientDB ODocuments.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually tried installing this plugin myself, but unsuccessfully alas. I'll document what I've tried.

Comment: OK, I think I've hacked it into shape. Will post my findings in a couple of days perhaps.